# Adding IF Conditional statement inside the query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

[image]

Hi,

I would like to ask help regarding my simple inventory using MS ACCESS 2013. I would like to create an automatic status update in one of my query table, as you can see on the image above there is a code written inside the status column. That code is working, if the EmployeeID field is empty it show's "available" on the status. Now, how do I display Not Available if the EmployeeID is populated?

Comment: Please don't just screenshot your code. Edit it as code snippet in your question

Comment: Will do next time nephew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with - as *EmployeeID* hardly can be an empty string):

```
Status: IIf([EmployeeID] Is Null, "Available", "Not available"))
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooooooo much.

Comment: I just have one issue right now, the status field on my Device Lists table is not picking up the data from the status field on my Device List Query. The "Available and Not Available" is showing up in the query but not in the original table.

Comment: That is right. The table can't see what's going on the query. Where you need the "Availble/Not available", use the query, not the table as source.

Comment: Try with - as EmployeeID hardly can be an empty string):

`Status: IIf([EmployeeID] Is Null, "Available", "Not available")`

What if I want to use this code on numbers instead of string.

Comment: It only checks if _EmployeeID_ is _Null_ or not, thus it can be text or number as you like.

Comment: Done sir, thank you very much for all your informative responses.

Comment: Hi, is there anyway that I can use this code `Status: IIf([EmployeeID] Is Null, "Available", "Not available")`to my database table instead of applying it on Query table?

Comment: Is it possible to apply it directly to the database table using MACRO? if it's possible then could you please show me how?

Comment: It might - as a calculated field. But refrain from that; it's a dead end. Queries are exactly for this and will impose zero drawbacks.

Comment: I've already done doing that in the query but yet, I'm still not quiet satisfied since the status value only appears on the query table. Is there anyway that the status column in my query table can update the status column inside my database table. As you have said recently, The table can't see what's going on the query. Where you need the "Availble/Not available", use the query, not the table as source. But there must be another way to do this.

Comment: But there is no problems in using the query. Whenever you need the status field, use the query as source, not the table. This is common practice.